# java test score statistics

Tags: java, loops

This is the task:

- Display the usage message "Please input test scores with values between 0-100.
- Enter 999 to finish."
- Accept test scores within the range 0-100. If the number is out of range, display the message "Invalid Test Score", disregard that input and continue collecting values
- Stop collecting test scores when the user inputs the number 999
- Once all values have been entered, display the number of scores entered, the lowest score, the highest score, and the average.

Sample output for input: `57 -2 98 13 85 77 999`

And this is my solution:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestScoreStatistics {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int max=0;
        int min=999;
        int avg=0;
        int count=0;
        int sum=0;
        int num;
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input test scores with values between 0-100.\nEnter 999 to finish.");
        num=scan.nextInt();
        int temp=num;

        do
        {
            if(num==999) 
                System.exit(0);

            if(num>=0 && num<=100)
            {
                count++;
                sum+=num;
                if(num>max ) 
                    max=num;
                if(num<min)
                    min=num;
            }
        } while((num=scan.nextInt())!=999);

        System.out.println("Test Statistics:");
        System.out.println("Number of tests: "+count);
        System.out.println("Lowest: "+min);
        System.out.println("Highest: "+max);;
        System.out.printf("Average: " + sum/count);
    }
}
```

but when input is 999 the output should be 
Test Statistics: 
Number of Tests: 0 
Lowest: 0 
Highest: 0 
Average: 0
how do I do that?

Comment: please indent well, your code is not readable ...

Comment: Please quote the content in the description part. It looks like an essay now.

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  See also: [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You say you want to show the statistics one you entered all the values, which happens when you type 999, but you want to show all the values as 0 when you type 999. Which one is it? (I'm guessing the first option).

Comment: It would be easier if you would first read all user input into a List<Integer> and then perform validation and output calculation.

Comment: @Guy I think that OP's intention in last sentence was to show all statistics with `0`s when the first input given by user is `999`. Currently, in OP's code, when first input is equal to `999`, System.exit(0) is immediately performed, so there are no statistics shown.

Answer (score 3):

This is what i would do. If it is as assigment for your programming classes, I would suggest replacing the lines with collections etc. with some other code (you can find that on stackoverflow)

```
    List<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<>();

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input test scores with values between 0-100. Enter 999 to finish.");
    int num = scan.nextInt();

    do {
        if (num == 999)
            break;

        if (num >= 0 && num <= 100) {
            scores.add(num);
        }
    }

    while ((num = scan.nextInt()) != 999);
    if (scores.size() != 0) {
        System.out.println("Test Statistics:");
        System.out.println("Number of tests: " + scores.size());
        System.out.println("Lowest: " + scores.indexOf(Collections.min(scores)));
        System.out.println("Highest: " + scores.indexOf(Collections.max(scores)));
        System.out.printf("Average: " + scores.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum() / scores.size());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Test Statistics:");
        System.out.println("Number of tests: 0");
        System.out.println("Lowest: 0 *or write whatever you want here");
        System.out.println("Highest: 0");
        System.out.printf("Average: 0");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider changing:

```
if(num==999) 
    System.exit(0);
```

to:

```
if(num==999) 
    break;
```

It will cause exiting `do-while` loop instead of finishing a program when your first input is "`999`". The problem you will need to solve then is dividing by 0 here:

```
System.out.printf("Average: " + sum/count);
```

You can change it to something like this:

```
if (count == 0) {
    System.out.printf("Average: 0"); // Show average as 0 here, when count is equal to 0.
} else {
    System.out.printf("Average: " + sum / count);
}
```

or something similar what you need to perform instead of dividing by 0 there.